# Second input char* makes infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

Below is my C code. The very first input works beautifully, but the second causes an infinite loop. I've flushed the buffer, and I do not have any clue how to solve this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAXARG 7

int main()
{
    char buf[256];
    char* arg[MAXARG];
    char* s;
    char* save;
    int argv;

    static const char delim[] = " \t\n";
    int pid, status;

    while(1){
        printf("MyShell: ");
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        argv = 0;

        s = strtok_r(buf, delim, &save);

        while(s){
            arg[argv++] = s;
            s= strtok_r(NULL, delim, &save);
        }

        arg[argv] = (char*) 0;

        if(!strcmp(arg[0], "quit"))
            break;
        if((pid = fork()) == -1)
            perror("fork failed...");
        else if(pid != 0){
            pid = wait(&status);
        }
        else{
            execvp(arg[0], arg);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically, using `fflush` on an input stream is undefined behavior.

Comment: As for your problem, you might want to try and step through the code line by line in a debugger. It might help.

Comment: use fflush above fgets

Comment: Or be the wiser, and don't use fflush() *at all* on an input stream. It is as Joachim pointed out: **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy The fflush function is documented to cause any unwritten data for that stream to be written to the file. Do you want to *write* to stdin? Is this like flushing the toilet and having the toilet bowl fill up with previously flushed waste?

Comment: @Christopher Pfohl Thanks for editing my lacking(?) English :D

Comment: No problem. You're English was certainly clear enough, but some people like to downvote imperfect English, which is *not* helpful for Stack Overflow, *or* the questioner. 안녕하세요 (Google Translate; I don't speak Korean)

Answer (score 0):

use `fflush` above `fgets`..
u need to flush the `stdin` before you enter the message..

you can use `__fpurge` in `linux` which is in stdio_ext header..

Comment: Section 7.21.5.2, paragraph 2 of the C standard makes it clear that `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour: *If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream
to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined.*

Comment: Please describe the behaviour that you expect from `fflush` on an input stream, and I'll attempt to demonstrate to you that you don't need to rely on the coincidence that the stars have magically aligned to produce your desired behaviour.

Comment: you mean <stdio_ext.h>? my xcode said it can not find such header. Anyway fpurg() thing is you are right. thanks. I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that you call `fgets()`, then you call `fflush()` and do your work... then you loop around the `while` and call `fgets()` again... but you're not testing for `EOF` from `fgets()` which I can all but guarantee you are getting. Now your `while` loop is endlessly cycling waiting for `fgets()` to return something other than `EOF`

Answer (score 0):

Worthy of a quick mention: When people write <strike>`fflush(stdin);`</strike>, they usually mean something like:

```
/* Read and discard the remainder of a line of input, because the remainder of
 * the line isn't of interest to us...
 */
void discard_line(FILE *f) {
    int c;
    do {
        c = fgetc(f);
    } while (c >= 0 && c != '\n');
}
```

`fflush` isn't defined to work on input streams such as `stdin`. <strike>`fflush(stdin);`</strike> might be doing what you expect, but that's only by coincidence. If you care at all about portability, you won't use `fflush` on input-only streams.

In fact, you may even consider reading manual pages for functions that you previously haven't, paying particular attention to [the section entitled "RETURN VALUE" of the "fgets" manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html#tag_03_164_04). You might include that return value in the condition for your loop, somehow, perhaps like:

```
/* Note how fflush is used on an output stream to ensure data is written
 * immediately to stdout. You'll only need to do this when your data doesn't
 * end in '\n', because data may not be written until a '\n' is written.
 */
printf("MyShell: "); fflush(stdout);
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == buf) {
    /* Find either the first '\n' or the first '\0', so we can work out whether
     * or not to discard anything...
     */
    size_t length = strcspn(buf, "\n");
    if (buf[length] != '\n') {
        /* If the line doesn't end in '\n', then we've read only part of a line.
         * Discard the rest? Okay...
         */
        discard_line(stdin);
    }

    /* Remove the '\n', if there is one. Otherwise, replace '\0' with '\0' ;) */
    buf[length] = '\0';
    /* TODO: Insert non-fflush(stdin)-related code here */

    printf("MyShell: "); fflush(stdout);
}
```

PS. I suggest reading the comments. They might be insightful.

Comment: thanks for let me learn your coding knowhow. but some reason, even though I've replaced input logic with yours it still fall into infinite loop. Do you have any idea left something I can still try?

Comment: I've tested "ls", "ps", "cal 04 2013". But problem is every second command becomes infinite loop. there's only one exception which is if first time you enter some command and erase that, and again put command, that problem doesn't happen